# how solve 401 error in SpringBoot Application?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, h2

I create SpringBoot Application and in tests used PostMan agent. When I try login as new user postman send me error

> "timestamp": "2021-04-06T12:22:09.052+00:00",
> "status": 401,
> "error": "Unauthorized",
> "trace": "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException:
> Bad credentials\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:141)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510)\r\n\tat
> com.aplikacja.Aplikacja.firmowa.Controller.UserController.authorizeUser(UserController.java:46)\r\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)\r\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> com.aplikacja.Aplikacja.firmowa.security.JWebToken.AuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthenticationTokenFilter.java:52)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:78)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:67)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\n",
> "message": "Error: Unauthorized",
> "path": "/user/authorize/login"
>
> }

My code looks like:
UserController:

```
> @CrossOrigin("*") @RestController @RequiredArgsConstructor
> @RequestMapping("/user") public class UserController {
> 
>     private final UserService userService;
>     private final UserMapper userMapper;
>     private final UserRepository userRepository;
>     private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
>     private final JWebTokenUtils jWebTokenUtils;
> 
>     @PostMapping("/authorize/login")
>     public ResponseEntity<?> authorizeUser(@Valid @RequestBody RequiredLogin requiredLogin) {
>         UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken loginAndPasswordAuth =
>                 new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(requiredLogin.getLogin(),
>                         requiredLogin.getPassword());
> 
>         Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
>                 .authenticate(loginAndPasswordAuth);
> 
>         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
>         String jWebToken = jWebTokenUtils.generateJWebToken(authentication);
> 
>         UserDetailsImpl userDetailsImpl = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
>         List<String> role = userDetailsImpl.getAuthorities().stream()
>                 .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());
> 
>         return ResponseEntity.ok(new JWebTokenResponse(jWebToken, userDetailsImpl.getId(),
>                 userDetailsImpl.getUsername(), userDetailsImpl.getEmail(), role));
>     }
> 
>     @PostMapping("/authorize/register")
>     public ResponseEntity<?> registerNewAdmin(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
>         if (userRepository.existsByLogin(userDto.getLogin())) {
>             return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ResponseMessage("Error: This username is taken"));
>         }
>         if (userRepository.existsByEmail(userDto.getEmail())) {
>             return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ResponseMessage("Error: this email address is in use"));
>         }
>         userService.addNewUser(userMapper.mapToUser(userDto));
> 
>         return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseMessage("New admin account is created successfully"));
>     }
> 
> }
```

Security Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPointJWebToken unauthorize;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(
                passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorize).and()
                .sessionManagement().
                sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

How can I solve this error?  From other hand register method works fine.

Comment: ".anyRequest().authenticated()" can you explain how you expect this to work?

Comment: It should work like this.
You create account. All data is saved in database. And when you try login you got information that this account is verificated. Than you log in.